# iOS core audio: synchronize play and record to high accuracy ( < 5ms error )

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm trying to:
- play a click track 
- record user audio through the internal iphone/ipad mic

I need the high accuracy for both the click track ( < 1ms jitter per click ) and the alignment of samples to the click ( < 1ms discrepancy of all the samples to the click vs. the real-world measurements )

I've studied the aurioTouch example and assume this is the best way to get low-latency/high-accuracy performance...Taking aurioTouch as a starting point, can anyone shed light on how to produce an accurate click as well as then synchronize the recorded audio to that click?  By this I mean I should know when relative to the click hits the various samples are located in time.  We can assume the user is wearing headphones so the click doesn't interfere with the recorded audio.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this reliably. An alternate and more reliable approach is to make sure that your generated clicks *do* get recorded, and then you can identify these in the recorded audio and make your measurements relative to these real world measured clicks.

Comment: Thanks PaulK---which part cannot be done reliably? The click part or the lining of recorded audio up with the click? Metronome Plus claims a highly-accurate metronome but doesn't cite any specific metrics...I'll let you know if I find out more about its performance. If you can produce an accurate click it seems weird you cannot then line up the recorded audio with that set of clicks....

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to synchronise recording with playback, so although the clicks may be accurately generated, there is no way to accurately synchronize recording with these clicks. However if you make sure the clicks are recorded and you can reliably identify them when they are combined with the other recorded sounds then you don't need to worry about synchronization.